# List Item should be non-editable once created by the user

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-list

I have a list and have contributor access to it. I want when an I create an item into it after that it should not be allowed to edit.

Comment: who shouldn't be allowed to edit? anyone other than the one who created it or everyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple ways to achieve this:

**Approach 1:**

1. Create a custom permission level with access only to create item and not delete, edit.
2. Break permissions if you want no one to edit the item.
3. Create a SharePoint Group and add users who are supposed to create items in the list or library.

Now only users will be able to create items and not able to edit or delete it. If want other users to be allowed remove or edit item, do not break permissions inheritance.

**Approach 2:**

1. Create a SharePoint Designer Workflow
2. Make the workflow to run only on item creation
3. Use "`Remove permissions`" action, select the creator of item. Do not use '`Replace Permissions`" action if you have huge no of user groups or users outside groups. Also if you do not want no one to edit or delete items.
4. Now Use Assign permissions action to set read only access to the creator of item.

Now this item will be allowed to be edited or deleted by anyone except creator. If want to restrict from all, use `Replace Permissions` action in *step 3*.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set up a permission level which only allows users to Add items.  Just make sure Edit Items, Delete Items, etc. isn't checked when creating the permission level.

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple SharePoint Designer workflow to remove permissions from the item.

Use the Replace List Item Permissions to remove contribute access and replace it with read access.